# Out of memory building Yocto with 32G of RAM

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, yocto

While building boot2qt using bitbake and Yocto, the build fail due to some sort of lack of memory.

What is strange is that I have 32G of RAM on this desktop.

This issue was diagnosed because of the "fatal error" message

```
| aarch64-poky-linux-g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
| compilation terminated.
| [24202/27248] CXX obj/content/browser/browser/audits_handler.o
| [24203/27248] CXX obj/content/browser/browser/system_info_handler.o
| [24204/27248] CXX obj/content/browser/browser/background_service_handler.o
| [24205/27248] CXX obj/content/browser/browser/dom_handler.o
| [24206/27248] CXX obj/content/browser/browser/handler_helpers.o
| [24207/27248] CXX obj/content/browser/browser/devtools_mhtml_helper.o
| [24208/27248] CXX obj/content/browser/browser/inspector_handler.o
| [24209/27248] CXX obj/content/browser/browser/emulation_handler.o
| [24210/27248] CXX obj/content/browser/browser/input_handler.o
| [24211/27248] CXX obj/content/browser/browser/io_handler.o
| [24212/27248] CXX obj/content/browser/browser/security_handler.o
| [24213/27248] CXX obj/content/browser/browser/overlay_handler.o
| [24214/27248] CXX obj/content/browser/browser/storage_handler.o
| [24215/27248] CXX obj/content/browser/browser/page_handler.o
| [24216/27248] CXX obj/content/browser/browser/service_worker_handler.o
| [24217/27248] CXX obj/content/browser/browser/network_handler.o
| ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
| FAILED: src/core/Release/aarch64/QtWebEngineCore.stamp src/core/Release/aarch64/QtWebEngineCore
| cd /home/bsp/yocto/testb2q/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-mx8mp-poky-linux/qtwebengine/6.2.1-r0/build/src/core && /home/bsp/yocto/testb2q/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-mx8mp-poky-linux/qtwebengine/6.2.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/ninja -C /home/bsp/yocto/testb2q/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-mx8mp-poky-linux/qtwebengine/6.2.1-r0/build/src/core/Release/aarch64 QtWebEngineCore
| ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: ExecutionError('/home/bsp/yocto/testb2q/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-mx8mp-poky-linux/qtwebengine/6.2.1-r0/temp/run.do_compile.3408041', 1, None, None)
ERROR: Task (/home/bsp/yocto/testb2q/sources/meta-qt6/recipes-qt/qt6/qtwebengine_git.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
```

Watching dmesg output, I've got the following one :

```
[9723286.547945] CPU: 11 PID: 3575743 Comm: cc1plus Not tainted 5.8.0-59-generic #66~20.04.1-Ubuntu
[9723286.547945] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Precision 3630 Tower/0Y2K8N, BIOS 2.5.0 02/05/2020
[9723286.547946] Call Trace:
[9723286.547950]  dump_stack+0x74/0x92
[9723286.547952]  dump_header+0x4f/0x1eb
[9723286.547953]  oom_kill_process.cold+0xb/0x10
[9723286.547955]  out_of_memory.part.0+0x1df/0x430
[9723286.547956]  out_of_memory+0x6d/0xd0
[9723286.547958]  __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.0+0xd02/0xe20
[9723286.547959]  ? get_page_from_freelist+0x68/0x370
[9723286.547961]  __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x2bc/0x2f0
[9723286.547963]  alloc_pages_current+0x87/0xe0
[9723286.547965]  __page_cache_alloc+0x72/0x90
[9723286.547966]  pagecache_get_page+0xbf/0x300
[9723286.547967]  filemap_fault+0x6ec/0xa70
[9723286.547969]  ? unlock_page_memcg+0x20/0x30
[9723286.547970]  ? page_add_file_rmap+0x14e/0x1c0
[9723286.547972]  ? filemap_map_pages+0x1d5/0x3b0
[9723286.547974]  ext4_filemap_fault+0x32/0x50
[9723286.547975]  __do_fault+0x3c/0xe0
[9723286.547976]  do_fault+0x256/0x520
[9723286.547977]  __handle_mm_fault+0x547/0x930
[9723286.547979]  handle_mm_fault+0xca/0x200
[9723286.547981]  do_user_addr_fault+0x1e2/0x440
[9723286.547983]  exc_page_fault+0x86/0x1b0
[9723286.547984]  ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x8/0x30
[9723286.547985]  asm_exc_page_fault+0x1e/0x30
[9723286.547987] RIP: 0033:0x6af5f0
[9723286.547990] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x6af5c6.
[9723286.547991] RSP: 002b:00007ffe65f95758 EFLAGS: 00010212
[9723286.547992] RAX: 0000000000000102 RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: 0000000000000018
[9723286.547994] RDX: 000000000078b9f3 RSI: 0000000000000102 RDI: 00007fa0a3685f90
[9723286.547995] RBP: 00007fa0a3697370 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 0000000800000110
[9723286.547995] R10: 000000080000ffff R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 00007fa0a3685f90
[9723286.547996] R13: 00007fa120eb6fc8 R14: 00007fa128ee4240 R15: 00007fa0a3692000
[9723286.547997] Mem-Info:
[9723286.548000] active_anon:7441586 inactive_anon:444318 isolated_anon:0
                  active_file:286 inactive_file:206 isolated_file:0
                  unevictable:29 dirty:4 writeback:0
                  slab_reclaimable:82980 slab_unreclaimable:100523
                  mapped:456 shmem:42 pagetables:20334 bounce:0
                  free:49710 free_pcp:2809 free_cma:0
[9723286.548002] Node 0 active_anon:29766344kB inactive_anon:1777272kB active_file:1144kB inactive_file:824kB unevictable:116kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:1824kB dirty:16kB writeback:0kB shmem:168kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 0kB writeback_tmp:0kB all_unreclaimable? no
[9723286.548003] Node 0 DMA free:11812kB min:32kB low:44kB high:56kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15992kB managed:15908kB mlocked:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
[9723286.548005] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 1801 31869 31869 31869
[9723286.548007] Node 0 DMA32 free:123344kB min:3816kB low:5660kB high:7504kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:1747320kB inactive_anon:1096kB active_file:284kB inactive_file:260kB unevictable:0kB writepending:4kB present:1964184kB managed:1898008kB mlocked:0kB kernel_stack:16kB pagetables:984kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:2668kB local_pcp:256kB free_cma:0kB
[9723286.548009] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 30067 30067 30067
[9723286.548011] Node 0 Normal free:63684kB min:63728kB low:94516kB high:125304kB reserved_highatomic:2048KB active_anon:28019024kB inactive_anon:1776176kB active_file:1712kB inactive_file:1356kB unevictable:116kB writepending:12kB present:31399936kB managed:30796924kB mlocked:0kB kernel_stack:12592kB pagetables:80352kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:8568kB local_pcp:924kB free_cma:0kB
[9723286.548013] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
[9723286.548015] Node 0 DMA: 1*4kB (U) 0*8kB 0*16kB 1*32kB (U) 2*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (M) 2*4096kB (M) = 11812kB
[9723286.548020] Node 0 DMA32: 113*4kB (UE) 166*8kB (UME) 225*16kB (UME) 293*32kB (UE) 240*64kB (UE) 151*128kB (UE) 95*256kB (UE) 47*512kB (UE) 23*1024kB (UME) 1*2048kB (E) 0*4096kB = 123428kB
[9723286.548026] Node 0 Normal: 1004*4kB (UMEH) 987*8kB (UME) 1821*16kB (UME) 706*32kB (UME) 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 63640kB
[9723286.548031] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
[9723286.548032] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
[9723286.548032] 1283 total pagecache pages
[9723286.548034] 385 pages in swap cache
[9723286.548034] Swap cache stats: add 5713873, delete 5729326, find 11334351/11955584
[9723286.548035] Free swap  = 0kB
[9723286.548036] Total swap = 2097148kB
[9723286.548036] 8345028 pages RAM
[9723286.548036] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
[9723286.548037] 167318 pages reserved
[9723286.548037] 0 pages hwpoisoned
[9723286.548037] Tasks state (memory values in pages):
[9723286.548038] [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
[9723286.548045] [    415]     0   415     1347        0    53248       49             0 blkmapd
[9723286.548048] [    825]     0   825      796        0    45056       44             0 rpc.idmapd
[9723286.548049] [    842]   128   842     1778        0    53248      150             0 rpcbind
[9723286.548050] [    866]     0   866    60057        0    98304      784             0 accounts-daemon
[9723286.548051] [    867]     0   867      637        0    40960       42             0 acpid
[9723286.548052] [    871]     0   871     2356       13    57344       54             0 cron
[9723286.548053] [    876]   103   876     2574       45    57344      703          -900 dbus-daemon
[9723286.548055] [    878]     0   878   235709       37   196608     1009             0 NetworkManager
[9723286.548056] [    884]     0   884    20487       39    61440       57             0 irqbalance
[9723286.548057] [    903]     0   903    60644      100   106496     2066             0 polkitd
[9723286.548058] [    906]   104   906    56089       89    81920      554             0 rsyslogd
[9723286.548060] [    912]     0   912    58929        0    86016      187             0 switcheroo-cont
[9723286.548061] [    913]     0   913     4457        4    77824      528             0 systemd-logind
[9723286.548062] [    920]     0   920     3422        7    65536      153             0 wpa_supplicant
[9723286.548063] [    998]     0   998     8010        2   102400     6303             0 rpc.mountd
[9723286.548065] [   1020]     0  1020    59971        1   102400      382             0 gdm3
[9723286.548066] [   1074]     0  1074    29537        0   122880     2064             0 unattended-upgr
[9723286.548068] [   1102]   111  1102    38235        0    61440       94             0 rtkit-daemon
[9723286.548069] [   1203]     0  1203    63026        0   102400      352             0 upowerd
[9723286.548070] [   1498]   121  1498   215251        0   180224     1431             0 colord
[9723286.548071] [   1598]   120  1598    81722       39   126976      514             0 whoopsie
[9723286.548072] [   1604]   116  1604     2816        0    61440      124             0 kerneloops
[9723286.548073] [   1611]   116  1611     2816       24    69632       96             0 kerneloops
[9723286.548074] [   1614]     0  1614      760        1    45056       31             0 in.tftpd
[9723286.548075] [   1660]     0  1660      269        0    28672        9             0 none
[9723286.548076] [   2777]     0  2777    59619        0    98304      273             0 boltd
[9723286.548077] [  26649]   115 26649     2160       45    57344       92             0 avahi-daemon
[9723286.548078] [  26650]   115 26650     2088        0    57344       83             0 avahi-daemon
[9723286.548081] [ 400998]     0 400998     9826        0   114688     2071             0 networkd-dispat
[9723286.548082] [ 424400]     0 424400     3046        0    65536      234         -1000 sshd
[9723286.548083] [ 633354]     0 633354    41672        0    98304      345             0 gdm-session-wor
[9723286.548085] [ 633360]   125 633360     4727        1    73728      525             0 systemd
[9723286.548086] [ 633361]   125 633361    42626        0   106496     1297             0 (sd-pam)
[9723286.548087] [ 633366]   125 633366   202129        0   155648     1132             0 pulseaudio
[9723286.548088] [ 633368]   125 633368   281737        0   253952     4605             0 tracker-miner-f
[9723286.548089] [ 633371]   125 633371     1901        1    57344      188             0 dbus-daemon
[9723286.548090] [ 633386]   125 633386    59929        0   102400      294             0 gvfsd
[9723286.548091] [ 633392]   125 633392    78202        0    98304      224             0 gvfsd-fuse
[9723286.548092] [ 633394]   125 633394    40413        1    77824      151             0 gdm-wayland-ses
[9723286.548093] [ 633402]   125 633402    78521       17   102400      480             0 gvfs-udisks2-vo
[9723286.548095] [ 633403]   125 633403     1325        0    49152       49             0 dbus-run-sessio
[9723286.548096] [ 633405]   125 633405     1916        1    49152      244             0 dbus-daemon
[9723286.548097] [ 633408]   125 633408   120968        0   155648      607             0 gnome-session-b
[9723286.548098] [ 633427]   125 633427    79182        0   110592      298             0 gvfs-afc-volume
[9723286.548099] [ 633436]   125 633436    59529        0    86016      249             0 gvfs-gphoto2-vo
[9723286.548100] [ 633437]   125 633437  1078302     2135  1163264    18256             0 gnome-shell
[9723286.548102] [ 633442]   125 633442    58970        0    86016      222             0 gvfs-goa-volume
[9723286.548103] [ 633446]   125 633446   136266        0   249856     1552             0 goa-daemon
[9723286.548104] [ 633457]   125 633457    78690        0   110592      405             0 goa-identity-se
[9723286.548106] [ 633464]   125 633464    58927        0    86016      209             0 gvfs-mtp-volume
[9723286.548107] [ 633497]   125 633497    76353        1    90112      188             0 at-spi-bus-laun
[9723286.548108] [ 633502]   125 633502     1812        0    57344      112             0 dbus-daemon
[9723286.548110] [ 633511]   125 633511   697750        0   593920     4940             0 Xwayland
[9723286.548111] [ 633529]   125 633529    58900        0    86016      156             0 xdg-permission-
[9723286.548112] [ 633539]   125 633539   732549        0   262144     1385             0 gjs
[9723286.548113] [ 633541]   125 633541    40693        0    86016      191             0 at-spi2-registr
[9723286.548114] [ 633553]   125 633553   116169        0   126976      483             0 gsd-sharing
[9723286.548115] [ 633554]   125 633554    84846        0   163840     1195             0 gsd-wacom
[9723286.548117] [ 633555]   125 633555   103765       59   176128     1153             0 gsd-color
[9723286.548118] [ 633556]   125 633556    84937        0   159744     1248             0 gsd-keyboard
[9723286.548119] [ 633557]   125 633557    62057        0   114688      389             0 gsd-print-notif
[9723286.548120] [ 633559]   125 633559   114276        0   114688      273             0 gsd-rfkill
[9723286.548121] [ 633561]   125 633561    78799        0   114688      265             0 gsd-smartcard
[9723286.548123] [ 633563]   125 633563    93413        0   172032      521             0 gsd-datetime
[9723286.548124] [ 633565]   125 633565   223826        0   212992     1351             0 gsd-media-keys
[9723286.548125] [ 633568]   125 633568    58878        1    81920      172             0 gsd-screensaver
[9723286.548126] [ 633572]   125 633572    79846        0   114688      295             0 gsd-sound
[9723286.548127] [ 633573]   125 633573    77423        0    94208      188             0 gsd-a11y-settin
[9723286.548128] [ 633577]   125 633577    77938       54   102400      155             0 gsd-housekeepin
[9723286.548129] [ 633584]   125 633584    85163        0   159744     1300             0 gsd-power
[9723286.548130] [ 633637]   125 633637    85549        1   147456      497             0 gsd-printer
[9723286.548131] [ 633700]   125 633700    77738        1    98304      358             0 ibus-daemon
[9723286.548132] [ 633706]   125 633706    59132        0    90112      189             0 ibus-dconf
[9723286.548133] [ 633708]   125 633708   147414        0   344064     2633             0 ibus-x11
[9723286.548134] [ 633710]   125 633710    59127        1    86016      180             0 ibus-portal
[9723286.548135] [ 633718]   125 633718    40675        0    86016      182             0 ibus-engine-sim
[9723286.548136] [ 649992]   125 649992    40563        0    81920      179             0 gvfsd-metadata
[9723286.548138] [2333160]  1001 2333160     4745       60    77824      462             0 systemd
[9723286.548139] [2333161]  1001 2333161    42658        0   106496     1301             0 (sd-pam)
[9723286.548140] [2333168]  1001 2333168   281253        0   262144     4077             0 tracker-miner-f
[9723286.548141] [2333180]  1001 2333180     1894        0    57344      183             0 dbus-daemon
[9723286.548142] [2333204]  1001 2333204    59930        0    94208      268             0 gvfsd
[9723286.548143] [2333210]  1001 2333210    94586        0    98304      273             0 gvfsd-fuse
[9723286.548144] [2333223]  1001 2333223    78523        0   106496      500             0 gvfs-udisks2-vo
[9723286.548145] [2333244]  1001 2333244    79182        0   110592      311             0 gvfs-afc-volume
[9723286.548146] [2333250]  1001 2333250    59496        0    90112      251             0 gvfs-gphoto2-vo
[9723286.548147] [2333255]  1001 2333255    58970        0    86016      225             0 gvfs-goa-volume
[9723286.548149] [2333259]  1001 2333259   136274       24   258048     1503             0 goa-daemon
[9723286.548150] [2333268]  1001 2333268    78690        0   106496      436             0 goa-identity-se
[9723286.548151] [2333273]  1001 2333273    58927        1    86016      183             0 gvfs-mtp-volume
[9723286.548152] [2333545]  1001 2333545    27129        1   196608    12687             0 Cooker
[9723286.548154] [1171535]  1001 1171535    26822        1   188416    12399             0 Cooker
[9723286.548155] [1173926]  1001 1173926    26838        1   184320    12416             0 Cooker
[9723286.548156] [1227754]  1001 1227754    26838        1   192512    12416             0 Cooker
[9723286.548158] [1228747]  1001 1228747    26934        1   192512    12464             0 Cooker
[9723286.548159] [1280270]  1001 1280270    40563        0    77824      174             0 gvfsd-metadata
[9723286.548160] [1880382]     0 1880382     7140       23    90112      415             0 cupsd
[9723286.548162] [1880384]     0 1880384    44600       10   114688      436             0 cups-browsed
[9723286.548163] [1910558]     0 1910558    38580     1084   176128     1057             0 gitlab-runner
[9723286.548164] [1910660]     0 1910660     5889        0    65536      770         -1000 systemd-udevd
[9723286.548166] [1910737]     0 1910737   576434      275   401408     3333          -999 containerd
[9723286.548168] [1910792]     0 1910792    31569       32   106496      199             0 thermald
[9723286.548169] [1911225]     0 1911225     9173       47   106496      482             0 nmbd
[9723286.548170] [1911235]     0 1911235    12932       19   139264      688             0 smbd
[9723286.548171] [1911237]     0 1911237    12344        8   122880      667             0 smbd-notifyd
[9723286.548172] [1911238]     0 1911238    12346       12   122880      663             0 cleanupd
[9723286.548173] [1911239]     0 1911239    13059       21   131072      687             0 lpqd
[9723286.548174] [1911288]     0 1911288    78616        8   114688      441             0 ModemManager
[9723286.548175] [1911344]   101 1911344     5981       31    90112      992             0 systemd-resolve
[9723286.548176] [1911348]     0 1911348    39510       56   290816      236          -250 systemd-journal
[9723286.548178] [1911437]   102 1911437    22565       14    77824      198             0 systemd-timesyn
[9723286.548179] [1911547]     0 1911547   729816        0   479232     3561          -900 snapd
[9723286.548180] [1911733]     0 1911733    98305       42   122880      762             0 udisksd
[9723286.548182] [4105268]     0 4105268     3506        0    61440      371             0 sshd
[9723286.548183] [4105380]  1001 4105380     3772       40    65536      691             0 sshd
[9723286.548184] [4105381]  1001 4105381     2783        1    57344      485             0 bash
[9723286.548185] [4105565]  1001 4105565    27956        1   200704    13521             0 Cooker
[9723286.548186] [ 129432]     0 129432     3505        0    69632      370             0 sshd
[9723286.548187] [ 129943]  1001 129943     3505        0    69632      390             0 sshd
[9723286.548188] [ 129960]  1001 129960     2785        1    53248      471             0 bash
[9723286.548190] [3387451]  1001 3387451    39267      586   155648     5766             0 KnottyUI
[9723286.548191] [3387453]  1001 3387453   133294    14565  1077248   104289             0 Cooker
[9723286.548192] [3387463]  1001 3387463    27791      135   200704    13169             0 Cooker
[9723286.548193] [3387533]  1001 3387533    66377     1485   389120    32165             0 Worker
[9723286.548194] [3393818]  1001 3393818     1286        1    49152       48             0 pseudo
[9723286.548195] [3393819]  1001 3393819    66548      572   385024    33160             0 Worker (Fakeroo
[9723286.548196] [3408041]  1001 3408041    67345     1512   393216    33044             0 qtwebengine:com
[9723286.548197] [3408068]  1001 3408068      656        0    49152       34             0 run.do_compile.
[9723286.548199] [3408071]  1001 3408071     5584        0    81920      432             0 cmake
[9723286.548199] [3408073]  1001 3408073     1997        1    49152      544             0 ninja
[9723286.548201] [3409224]  1001 3409224      656        0    40960       26             0 sh
[9723286.548202] [3409225]  1001 3409225    59961     9943   524288    48343             0 ninja
[9723286.548203] [3537609]  1001 3537609    71249     1789   421888    36704             0 tesseract-lang:
[9723286.548204] [3537764]  1001 3537764      655        0    40960       26             0 sh
[9723286.548205] [3537765]  1001 3537765     3797       26    69632      175             0 wget
[9723286.548206] [3575697]  1001 3575697      658        0    40960       39             0 sh
[9723286.548207] [3575698]  1001 3575698      963        0    49152       75             0 aarch64-poky-li
[9723286.548208] [3575699]  1001 3575699   694147   621257  5459968    42592             0 cc1plus
[9723286.548209] [3575700]  1001 3575700    25399        1    61440      241             0 as
[9723286.548210] [3575709]  1001 3575709      658        0    40960       38             0 sh
[9723286.548212] [3575710]  1001 3575710      966        0    40960       74             0 aarch64-poky-li
[9723286.548213] [3575711]  1001 3575711   647365   588287  5091328    28596             0 cc1plus
[9723286.548214] [3575712]  1001 3575712    25399        1    57344      240             0 as
[9723286.548215] [3575713]  1001 3575713      658        0    45056       38             0 sh
[9723286.548217] [3575714]  1001 3575714      963        0    40960       75             0 aarch64-poky-li
[9723286.548218] [3575715]  1001 3575715   656604   612964  5173248    13996             0 cc1plus
[9723286.548219] [3575716]  1001 3575716    25399        0    57344      241             0 as
[9723286.548220] [3575729]  1001 3575729      658       22    40960        0             0 sh
[9723286.548222] [3575730]  1001 3575730      963       73    45056        0             0 aarch64-poky-li
[9723286.548223] [3575731]  1001 3575731   609831   581630  4800512       45             0 cc1plus
[9723286.548224] [3575732]  1001 3575732    25399      229    61440        0             0 as
[9723286.548225] [3575737]  1001 3575737      658       22    45056        0             0 sh
[9723286.548226] [3575738]  1001 3575738      966       49    45056        0             0 aarch64-poky-li
[9723286.548227] [3575739]  1001 3575739   607266   578398  4780032       12             0 cc1plus
[9723286.548228] [3575740]  1001 3575740    25399      229    65536        0             0 as
[9723286.548230] [3575741]  1001 3575741      658       22    45056        0             0 sh
[9723286.548231] [3575742]  1001 3575742      966       49    40960        0             0 aarch64-poky-li
[9723286.548232] [3575743]  1001 3575743   573813   545250  4505600        0             0 cc1plus
[9723286.548233] [3575744]  1001 3575744    25399      232    57344        0             0 as
[9723286.548234] [3575749]  1001 3575749      658       21    45056        0             0 sh
[9723286.548235] [3575750]  1001 3575750      966       49    40960        0             0 aarch64-poky-li
[9723286.548236] [3575751]  1001 3575751   542659   513449  4251648        0             0 cc1plus
[9723286.548237] [3575752]  1001 3575752    25399      232    65536        0             0 as
[9723286.548238] [3575753]  1001 3575753      658       21    40960        0             0 sh
[9723286.548239] [3575754]  1001 3575754      966       50    40960        0             0 aarch64-poky-li
[9723286.548240] [3575755]  1001 3575755   539649   510367  4231168        0             0 cc1plus
[9723286.548241] [3575756]  1001 3575756    25399      228    61440        0             0 as
[9723286.548242] [3575757]  1001 3575757      658       22    40960        0             0 sh
[9723286.548243] [3575758]  1001 3575758      966       50    45056        0             0 aarch64-poky-li
[9723286.548245] [3575759]  1001 3575759   499830   470401  3915776        0             0 cc1plus
[9723286.548246] [3575760]  1001 3575760    25399      229    57344        0             0 as
[9723286.548247] [3575761]  1001 3575761      658       21    45056        0             0 sh
[9723286.548249] [3575762]  1001 3575762      966       50    45056        0             0 aarch64-poky-li
[9723286.548250] [3575763]  1001 3575763   447043   417212  3493888        0             0 cc1plus
[9723286.548251] [3575764]  1001 3575764    25399      229    57344        0             0 as
[9723286.548252] [3575773]  1001 3575773      658       21    45056        0             0 sh
[9723286.548253] [3575774]  1001 3575774      966       50    45056        0             0 aarch64-poky-li
[9723286.548254] [3575775]  1001 3575775   426691   398541  3330048        0             0 cc1plus
[9723286.548255] [3575776]  1001 3575776    25399      227    65536        0             0 as
[9723286.548257] [3575777]  1001 3575777      658       22    45056        0             0 sh
[9723286.548258] [3575778]  1001 3575778      966       49    40960        0             0 aarch64-poky-li
[9723286.548258] [3575779]  1001 3575779   409408   380360  3198976        0             0 cc1plus
[9723286.548260] [3575780]  1001 3575780    25399      231    57344        0             0 as
[9723286.548262] [3575781]  1001 3575781      658       21    49152        0             0 sh
[9723286.548263] [3575782]  1001 3575782      966       49    45056        0             0 aarch64-poky-li
[9723286.548264] [3575783]  1001 3575783   393230   363799  3055616        0             0 cc1plus
[9723286.548265] [3575784]  1001 3575784    25399      227    69632        0             0 as
[9723286.548266] [3575789]  1001 3575789      658       21    45056        0             0 sh
[9723286.548267] [3575790]  1001 3575790      966       48    40960        0             0 aarch64-poky-li
[9723286.548268] [3575791]  1001 3575791   378691   348972  2945024        0             0 cc1plus
[9723286.548270] [3575792]  1001 3575792    25399      229    65536        0             0 as
[9723286.548271] [3575793]  1001 3575793      658       21    45056        0             0 sh
[9723286.548272] [3575794]  1001 3575794      963       72    40960        0             0 aarch64-poky-li
[9723286.548273] [3575795]  1001 3575795   364924   336452  2846720        0             0 cc1plus
[9723286.548274] [3575796]  1001 3575796    25399      233    69632        0             0 as
[9723286.548274] [3575797]  1001 3575797      658       21    40960        0             0 sh
[9723286.548275] [3575798]  1001 3575798      966       49    40960        0             0 aarch64-poky-li
[9723286.548276] [3575799]  1001 3575799   360062   326759  2789376        0             0 cc1plus
[9723286.548277] [3575800]  1001 3575800    25399      227    57344        0             0 as
[9723286.548278] [3575801]  1001 3575801      658       21    49152        0             0 sh
[9723286.548279] [3575802]  1001 3575802      963       73    45056        0             0 aarch64-poky-li
[9723286.548280] [3575803]  1001 3575803   272519   251273  2162688        0             0 cc1plus
[9723286.548281] [3575804]  1001 3575804    25399      227    69632        0             0 as
[9723286.548282] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice/user-1001.slice/session-5875.scope,task=cc1plus,pid=3575699,uid=1001
[9723286.548289] Out of memory: Killed process 3575699 (cc1plus) total-vm:2776588kB, anon-rss:2485028kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1001 pgtables:5332kB oom_score_adj:0
[9723286.625624] oom_reaper: reaped process 3575699 (cc1plus), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Is there any way to get out of this issue?

Regarding previous messaging, my gitlab-runner invoked oom-killer too.

How is it possible with this amount of memory?

Answer (score 3):

The Yocto build RAM consumption also depends on number of CPU cores.

As a workaround, you can either omit `qtwebengine` from the build if you don't need it, or experiment with the `BB_NUMBER_THREADS` and/or `PARALLEL_MAKE` variables which could be set in `local.conf` or prepended as a global variable in a bitbake call:

```
$ BB_NUMBER_THREADS=1 bitbake your-image
```

By limiting the number of compiler threads you could fit into your RAM amount.

Comment: Thanks for this reply.

Omiting `qtwebengine` works but it's that package that I want to use.

I've tried adding `BB_NUMBER_THREADS` and `PARALLEL_MAKE` to my local.conf as following but it doesn't reduce the number of tasks, every core is used and htop is full of compiling tasks:
`BB_NUMBER_THREADS = "1"
PARALLEL_MAKE     = "-j 1"`

Answer (score 0):

You could try first try to build qtwebengine. Then it is cached and then build whole image. If example qtwebengine still not run then limit threads so that it will run. You could raise those up with your image.

```
bitbake qtwebengine
bitbake your-image
```

Usually Yocto recommend over 2gb ram per virtual-core. So 32gb is good for about 8 core processor with smt on. This depends greatly what are you building.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you fixed your issue. I had a similar issue, but it was at the linking stages of `nodejs` - which took the best part of 32GB of memory in total (I only had 20GB assigned in my VM).

So my work around was to do one of:

- Assign larger swap memory (https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space) - I whacked it up to 32GB - this can take the slack from the RAM, but its obviously slower to use - however if its only for a short period then this works well enough.
- Get more RAM and assign it